# How to wrap a finite loop and push it out to a limited table in JS

Tags: javascript, date, for-loop

I'm working on this shorthand calendar, displaying `today` and following 5 days.
I got as far as to getting my loop started from `today`. There's a JS object with 7 days and a `for loop` that checks which day of those 7 is `today`; after this check is performed, loop replaces day name with word `today`. What I need to finish this thing is a way to wrap the outcomes, so after reaching the last day, functions wrap the loop and display missing days from the begginning of the array, if neccessary. For example, if today is Wednesday, it would display `Today, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday` and then wrap and display `Monday`.
But for now I managed only to crash my browser.
The code:

```js
var days = {
  weekDays: [{
    day: "monday",
    dayId: "1",
  }, {
    day: "tuesday",
    dayId: "2",
  }, {
    day: "wednesday",
    dayId: "3",
  }, {
    day: "thursday",
    dayId: "4",
  }, {
    day: "friday",
    dayId: "5",
  }, {
    day: "saturday",
    dayId: "6",
  }, {
    day: "sunday",
    dayId: "7",
  }, ]
}
var weekDays = days.weekDays;
var date = new Date;
var todaysDate = date.getDay();
var oneOfTheseDays = [];

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (weekDays[i].dayId == todaysDate) {
    weekDays[i].day = 'today';
  }
  var today = weekDays[i + todaysDate - 1];
  oneOfTheseDays.push(today);
}

console.log((oneOfTheseDays[0].day) + " " + (oneOfTheseDays[0].dayId));
```

I will be greatly appreciative of any support, for I'm going slightly mad here :(

Comment: Crashing reason is "out of index error?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `modulo` operator to wrap up your index.

e.g :

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (weekDays[i % 7].dayId == todaysDate) { // Won't exceed 6
        weekDays[i % 7].day = 'today'; // Won't exceed 6
    }
    var today = weekDays[(i + todaysDate - 1) % 7]; // Won't exceed 6
    oneOfTheseDays.push(today);
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are made of awesome!

Answer (score 1):

> `getDate()` => Get date from the date object
>
> `setdate()` => Update `dateObject` with new Date
>
> `getDay()` => get Day of the week(*0-6*)

```js
var date = new Date();
var daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var oneOfTheseDays = ['Today'];
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var d = daysInWeek[date.getDay()];
  oneOfTheseDays.push(d);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(oneOfTheseDays);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```